# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

In my php script I have GET data which contains the user's ID and then I am trying to delete the row which has the same ID. When I run my script I am getting the following error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING) . Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
$delete_query = DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = $ID;
$sendDeleteQuery = mysqli_query($dbc,$delete_query);
}
```

I googled the error, and it says that it happens when a string does not have quotations. I do not know where these quotations would go, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: `$delete_query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = $ID";`

Comment: I hope nobody sends "`ID`" as ID, because that would delete all rows in that table! (Please research [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in mysqli_*)

Comment: why do people start to code without understanding the very basics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in PHP are delimited by quotes. Your SQL query has no quotes around it.

```
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = $ID";
```

Comment: Close, but not always. heredoc/nowdoc doesn't require strings to be surrounded by quotes. :)

Comment: @Adrian: I'm not going to dive into the innards of PHP with the guy who forgot to put quotes around his string though.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
$delete_query = DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = $ID;
```

To,

```
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = $ID";
```

Or,

```
$delete_query = 'DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID = ' . $ID;
```

It is also recommended to clean your input ($_GET['ID']), before using this in a query.